# Kivy recycleview trouble displaying complex widgets

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm having having trouble with adding complex widgets to recycleview, mainly with the size. Recycleview seems to have size limits for the stuff in each row.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
    
Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.10.0
    
<RecycleViewRow>:
    size_hint_y: None
    size: "180dp", "280dp"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: 10
    border_radius: 20
    radius: [15]
    elevation:0
    MDLabel:
        text: root.text
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        font_style: "H6"
        font_size: "20sp"
        text_color: (0/255.0,141/255.0,155/255.0,255/255.0)
                            
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: 20, 0
        MDBoxLayout:
            MDLabel:
                text: "State: "
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                font_style: "Subtitle2"
                font_size: "14sp"
                text_color: (0/255.0,141/255.0,155/255.0,255/255.0)
        MDLabel:
            text: "state name"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            font_style: "Body2"
            font_size: "12sp"
            text_color: (0/255.0,141/255.0,155/255.0,255/255.0)   
    MDBoxLayout:
        MDLabel:
            text: "City: "
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            font_style: "Subtitle2"
            font_size: "14sp"
            text_color: (0/255.0,141/255.0,155/255.0,255/255.0)
        MDLabel:
            text: "city name"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            font_style: "Body2"
            font_size: "12sp"
            text_color: (0/255.0,141/255.0,155/255.0,255/255.0)   
    MDBoxLayout:
        MDLabel:
            text: "Locality: "
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            font_style: "Subtitle2"
            font_size: "14sp"
            text_color: (0/255.0,141/255.0,155/255.0,255/255.0)
        MDLabel:
            text: "locality name"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            font_style: "Body2"
            font_size: "12sp"
            text_color: (0/255.0,141/255.0,155/255.0,255/255.0)
    MDBoxLayout:
        MDLabel:
            text: "Pincode: "
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            font_style: "Subtitle2"
            font_size: "14sp"
            text_color: (0/255.0,141/255.0,155/255.0,255/255.0)
        MDLabel:
            text: "pincode"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            font_style: "Body2"
            font_size: "12sp"
            text_color: (0/255.0,141/255.0,155/255.0,255/255.0)   
    MDBoxLayout:
        MDLabel:
            text: "Last Verified: "
            theme_text_color: "Error"
            font_style: "Subtitle2"  
        MDLabel:
            text: "verification time"
            theme_text_color: "Error"
            font_style: "Subtitle2"
            font_size: "14sp"
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Get Details"
        md_bg_color: 0/255.0,141/255.0,155/255.0,255/255.0
    
<MainScreen>:
    viewclass: 'RecycleViewRow'
    RecycleGridLayout:
        cols:1
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'                    
''')
    
    
class RecycleViewRow(MDCard):
    text = StringProperty()   
    
class MainScreen(RecycleView):    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': "Button " + str(x), 'id': str(x)} for x in range(100)]
    

    
class TestApp(MDApp):
    title = "RecycleView Direct Test"
    
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUnde.png)

[This is how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixxDq.png)

I've already accomplished this with a normal scrollview, but it takes too long to generate all the boxes and their contents as I need to generate many of those.

Like I said below, I figured this part out, but know I'm having trouble aligning it to the center. Like if I decrease the width, and I need to do that, it stays on the left. I even tried putting the recycleview into an anchorlayout, but it didn't get anchored.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say but you are using the recycle view incorrectly. There are 4 components to the recycle behavior.

1. RecycleView
2. RecycleLayout
3. viewclass
4. data.

RecycleView is the base widget. Inside of RecycleView is the RecycleLayout. It determines the layout of the *RecycleChildrenWidgets*. The truth is that the *RecycleChildrenWidgets* don't exists as a widget you create but as a dictionary. These dictionaries are stored in **RecycleView.data**, a list.  The dictionaries contains the values for the attributes of the widgets. The widget type is set in RecycleView under **viewclass'** attribute.
So, you need to create a custom widget with attributes that are similiar to the {attribute:value} of your dictionaries in the **data** list. 
Follow the examples in the link. https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html 

If you do not want to take that route, you could use a [ScrollView](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html) widget instead.

Comment: Oh ok thanks. So which viewclass should I use for this ? The documentation doesn't exactly show the options I have for that. Cause this won't fit under Label. I was using scrollview, but I'm loading many widgets so it takes way too long to load. Are there any other alternatives to load multiple widgets quickly ?

Comment: @andril you could create your own class and pass its name as a string into *viewclass*. Any properties you want defined in your widget you could put as an *id* in *root*.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. I had to change the default_size value. Honestly the documentation for recycleview needs some work, although I suppose I should have gone through it carefully.